# Can't instantiate class error in JSF

Tags: java

Here is my managed Bean class,

public class MapBean implements Serializable {

```
private MapModel polylineModel;
public MapBean() {
    createMap();
}

 public void createMap(){
    try {
        polylineModel = new DefaultMapModel();
        LatLng coord;
        String query = "select a.lan,a.lat from country;";  
        Connector conn = new Connector();
        Statement str = (Statement) conn.getConn().createStatement();
        ResultSet res = str.executeQuery(query);
        Polyline polyline1;
        polyline1 = new Polyline();
        while(res.next()){
            coord= new LatLng(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(2)), Integer.parseInt(res.getString(1))); 

            polyline1.getPaths().add(coord); 
     }
        polyline1.setStrokeWeight(10);  
        polyline1.setStrokeColor("#FF9900");  
        polyline1.setStrokeOpacity(0.7);  

        polylineModel.addOverlay(polyline1);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MapBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }




 }
  public MapModel getPolylineModel() {  
    return polylineModel;  
}  

public void onPolylineSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event) {  
    addMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Polyline Selected", null));  
}  

public void addMessage(FacesMessage message) {  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
}
```

}
But the problem is when it is compiled it gives an error like this "Cant instantiate class: org.primefaces.examples.view.MapBean". What is the reason??

Comment: I don't know either. Do you have a stack trace or any other additional information?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7.421558"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:456)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
 at org.primefaces.examples.view.MapBean.createMap(MapBean.java:56)
 at org.primefaces.examples.view.MapBean.<init>(MapBean.java:42)

Comment: coord= new LatLng(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(2)), Integer.parseInt(res.getString(1))); seems here your are getting error, lat lang returning double or float value.

Answer (score 1):

use this code if LatLng supports double.

```
coord= new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(res.getString(2)), Double.parseDouble(res.getString(1)));
```